# Not update visual cells in a tableviewcell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I'm programming an app with a tableviewcell. When I touch a cell drives me to another view controller where I activate a switch and save this status on a plist file. Back to tableviewcell I read the information from the plist file and update the background color of the cell touched and activated. The problem is when I go back to the tableview cell though the navigation button, if the cell is visible doesn't show the background colored. Only if I scroll down or up, the color cell is updated. I have tried to reloadData method, but not success. On the IOS API says the visible cells will be updated with the reloadData method. Thanks in advance.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
controladorRegistre = [[ControladorRegistres alloc]initRegistreAmbCategoria];
[self.tableCategories reloadData];
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell       *)cell
            forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//Pinta la celda si esta activada
registre = [controladorRegistre getRegistreCategoria:cell.textLabel.text];
BOOL estaActivat = [[registre objectForKey:@"estaActivat"] boolValue];
if (estaActivat) {
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}else{
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
}
```

Comment: Did you check if `willDisplayCell` is being called?

Comment: It is called, but when I come back from the child view it is not, until I scroll down or up, then it is and the color cell is updated.

Answer (score 0):

As `willDisplayCell` is not called automatically when an already loaded cell becomes visible when transitioning from another view controller, you will have to put your update code into `viewWillAppear`.

I usually break this out into a separate method like `updateCells`.

In general, you can access the relevant cells with `[_tableView visibleCells]` or `indexPathsForVisibleCells`. In your case, you could keep a reference of the selected cell that started the second view controller and use that.